# Is it possible to use aov function in a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to calculate the anova value of smoke rate and some other factors in a data frame called 'rs_93'. It appeared that there os some problems in using aov function and for loop simultaneously.

I have used `str(rs_93)` and `class(rs_93)` to check that _rs_93_ is a data frame and used `is.atomic(rs_93)` to check that it is not an atomic vector.

```
for (i in 4:13){
  a<-cor(rs_93$smoke_rate,rs_93[,i])
  print(a)
  b<-summary(aov(rs_93$smoke_rate,rs_93[,i]))
  print(b)
}
```

> ```
> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> ```

Comment: `class(rs_93)` will probably give `matrix`, try `cor(rs_93[, "smoke_rate", rs_93[,i])` or convert `rs_93` to a data frame

Answer (score 0):

`aov` different than `cor` as it takes the variables as a formula, not as x,y as in `cor`, see `?aov`

> formula 
>   A formula specifying the model

Hence something like below will work, `mtcars` used for reproducibility

```
for(i in 3:6){
   print(cor(mtcars$mpg,mtcars[,i]))
   print(summary(aov(as.formula(paste('mpg','~',colnames(mtcars[i]))), data=mtcars)))
}
```